Prove that for $n$ sufficiently large and $k \leq n$, there exists $m$ having exactly $k$ divisors $\le n$

Prove that for all sufficiently large positive integers $n$ and a positive integer $k \leq n$, there exists a positive integer $m$ having exactly $k$ divisors in the set $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$.

here is my try
Not a solution. Haven't tried any sort of bash, so can provide only some sparse thoughts.
Let $d_k(n,x)$ be the number of positive integers $\le x$ with exactly $k$ divisors in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Obviously, it's enough to prove that $d_k(n,L)>0$, where $L=\mathrm{lcm}\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Them, by inclusion-exclusion, $$d_k(n,L)=\sum_{k\le r\le n}\binom rk(-1)^r\sum_{1\le d_1<\ldots<d_r\le n}\frac L{\mathrm{lcm}\{d_1,\ldots,d_k\}}.$$Note that this value is nonnegative, so it's enough to find a (not neccessarily) prime $p=p(k,n)$ so that $p\not\mid d_k(n,L)$. Maybe something like the largest $p\le n$ or so. I'm stuck here

Is this equivalent to proving the divisor function $\sigma_0(m)$ takes on every positive integer value of $k$?

No, as we're looking at divisors at most n.

Maybe we need some clarification. Do you mean "positive integer $m$ whose number of divisors in ${1,2,...,n}$ is exactly $k$"?

For example, $n!$ has exactly $n$ divisors in ${1,2,...,n}$?

@SungjinKim Yes, there is meant "positive integer $m$ whose number of divisors in ${1,2,\dots,n}$ is exactly $k$".

I will say that a divisor is small if it is at most $n$ and denote $s(m)$ as the number of small divisors of $m$.
Let $B$ be the set of primes more than $\frac{n}{2}$ but at most $n$. By the prime number theorem
$$\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\ln{n}} $$
and we have $|B| \sim \frac{n}{\ln{n}}-\frac{n}{2\left(\ln{n}-\ln{2}\right)} > \frac{n}{e\ln{n}}$ for large enough $n$.
What makes the elements of $B$ useful is the following Lemma.
Lemma 1: If $s(m) = \ell$ and $p\in B$ has $p \not \mid m$, then $s(pm) = \ell+1$.
Proof: The small divisors of $pm$ are precisely the $\ell$ small divisors of $m$, in addition to $p$. $\square$
Corollary 2: If $s(m) = \ell$ where $m$ is relatively prime to all elements of $B$, then for any $i \in [1, |B|]$ the equation $s(z) = \ell+i$ has a solution.
I now claim we can construct a sequence of numbers $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_t $ so that

We have $s(a_0) = 1$ and $s(a_t) = n-|B|$.
For all $p\in B, i\in [0, t]$, $p \not \mid a_i$.
For all $0\leq i < t$, $s(a_{i+1})-s(a_i)\leq |B|+1$.

If we find such a sequence then we would be done by applying Corollary $2$ to each of the terms.
Let $2 = p_1 < p_2<p_3< \ldots $ denote the primes in increasing order. Then take the sequence
$$a_0 = 1$$
$$a_1 =  \prod_{i = 1}^{\pi(3\ln{(n)})}p_i^{\lfloor \log_{p_i}(3\ln{n})\rfloor}$$
$$a_2 = a_1\cdot p_{1}$$
$$a_3 = a_2\cdot p_{1}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{n+1} = a_n\cdot p_{1} $$
$$a_{n+2} = a_{n+1}\cdot p_{2} $$
$$a_{n+3} = a_{n+2}\cdot p_{2} $$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{1+n(\pi(\frac{n}{2}))} = a_{n(\pi(\frac{n}{2}))}\cdot p_{\pi(\frac{n}{2})} $$
The point is that $a_1$ is a product over the primes at most $3\ln{n}$, where for each prime we multiply its largest power that is at most $3\ln{n}$. All of the other terms in the sequence multiply primes one at a time until the final term is a number which is a multiple of $\prod_{ i =1}^{\pi(\frac{n}{2})}p_i^n$ while not having any extra distinct prime divisors. The only numbers in $[1, n]$ that aren't small divisors of the final term are precisely the elements of $B$, as any number lacking lacking a prime divisor that's in $B$ will be a divisor of the final term, and any element of $B$ is not a divisor of the final term. Thus $s(a_t) = n-|B|$, proving condition $1$. Condition $2$ is clear by construction, so condition $3$ is left.
For $i\geq 1$, the only small divisors of $a_{i+1}$ that aren't small divisors of $a_i$ are multiples of a prime power that is at least $3\ln{n}$. There are at most $\frac{n}{3\ln{n}} < \frac{n}{e\ln{n}} < |B|$ multiples of said prime power that are even at most $n$, so we are good here.
For $i = 0$, it suffices to show that $a_1$ has at most $|B|$ divisors (let alone small ones). For sufficiently large $n$, the number of divisors of $a_1$ is
$$  \prod_{i = 1}^{\pi(3\ln{(n)})}\left(\lfloor \log_{p_i}(3\ln{n})\rfloor+1\right) = \prod_{i = 1}^{\pi(3\ln{(n)})}\left(\lfloor \frac{\ln{(3\ln{(n)})}}{\ln{p_i}}\rfloor+1\right) \leq \prod_{i = 1}^{\pi(3\ln{(n)})}2\cdot \left( \frac{\ln{(3\ln{(n)})}}{\ln{p_i}}\right) $$
Note that this is pretty small, since for "nearly all $p_i$" we have $\ln{p_i}\geq \ln{\sqrt{(3\ln{(n)})}} = \frac{\ln{(3\ln{(n)})}}{2}$ meaning $2\cdot \frac{\ln{(3\ln{(n)})}}{\ln{p_i}}\leq 4$. One can thus bound the above expression by splitting $p$ based on whether or not $p_i\geq \sqrt{(3\ln{(n)})}$. For simplicity I just googled this and found this bound by Greg Martin. With $x = 3\ln{n}$ lets go back to our bound and write it as
$$\prod_{i = 1}^{\pi(3\ln{(n)})}2\cdot \left( \frac{\ln{(3\ln{(n)})}}{\ln{p_i}}\right) = \frac{2^{\pi(x)}\cdot \left(\ln{x}\right)^{\pi(x)}}{\prod_{p_i\leq x} \ln{x}} $$
Taking the natural log of this expression and applying the hyper-linked bound gives a number at most
$$ \pi(x)\cdot \ln{2}+\pi(x)\ln{\ln{x}}-\left(\pi(x)\ln{\ln{x}}-\frac{Cx}{\log^2{x}}\right) = \pi(x)\cdot \ln{2}+\frac{Cx}{\log^2{x}}$$
for some constant $C>0$. Replacing $x$ with $3\ln{n}$ and applying prime number theorem gives
$$\pi(x)\cdot \ln{2}+\frac{Cx}{\log^2{x}} \sim \frac{3\ln{n}}{\ln{(3\ln{n})}}\cdot \ln{2}+\frac{C\cdot 3\ln{n}}{\log^2{(3\ln{n})}} \sim 3\ln{2}\cdot \frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{\ln{n}}}$$
On the other hand, the logarithm of $|B|$ is at least
$$\ln{\frac{n}{e\ln{n}}} = \ln{n}-\ln{\ln{n}}-1$$
so condition $3$ is proven (for large enough $n$ of course :P) and we are done!
